# Pasting from github markdown editor is different from pasting elsewhere

Tags: bash, shell, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

### Background

I've been documenting some useful scripts that I use when I ran into this issue...
I wanted syntax-highlighted code in a table, my first attempt was to use the original markdown ones like below, but couldn't get syntax highlighting to work

```
|   |   |
|---|---|
|   |   |
```

after some digging, I've found that html tables work too, so I went with that which results like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lXPd.png) 
However, when I tried to copy from the rendered markdown page or from anywhere besides the markdown editor within github (the rendered page, vscode...etc), it always gave me a newline which will cause errors when pasting into shell, can anyone tell me why this is occurring?

### Comparison

Copying from `github markdown editor` : [Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDyA7.png)

Pasting into shell : [Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugkQj.png)


Copying from `elsewhere (Web in this case)` : [Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXpnJ.png)

Pasting into shell : [Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYhXI.png)




*Sorry guys, reputation is too low for embedding picture (╥﹏╥)*

Comment: There is space behind \ . Also just remove the slash and put `|` on the of the line. `command |` <next line> `command`. Also don't use backticks, they are discouraged. Use `$( .. )`. And remember to `"` quote.

Comment: @KamilCuk though I indeed had an extra space, deleting it seems to not solve the problem...thanks though

Comment: When you copy there is an extra space behind \ . The \ has to be the last character on the line. If there is a space behind \ the space will be passed as argument. But, if the last char is `|` it can be followed by any number of space, tabs and newlines before the next command...

Comment: `why this is occurring?` - please post the actual markdown source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the slash and put the pipe character as the last character on the line:

```
ifconfig "$(route ... )" |
grep 'inet addr' | ... | awk '{print $1}'
```

That way no matter the spaces behind `|`, it will work.

Comment: Well, firstly, you should not copy some commands from the net without checking them. And obviously I am writing here for free, so I am way too lazy to copy your command from screenshots. Substitute the `...` dots for parts of your command. As you are seeing in your screenshot, the pipe was properly executed.

Comment: The post is about that you don't need it. You don't need it behind controls things, like `&` `&&` `||` `|` or really `;` which is interpreted the same way.

Comment: I see, my bad... I've actually placed  \ according to this [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/281334)

Comment: And some people prefer such style. Or don't know that you don't need it (like me for a long time until I joined stackoverflow). Just place `|` on the end of the line. You can even add comments behind `|` or on next newlines. Like `echo 123 |` <newline> `# comment` <newline> `cat`